# What's the best way to apply the Intel Pin tool to a service run via systemd?

Tags: linux, services

I want to use [Intel Pin Tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool.html) to instrument open-ssh server. I do not know any way to do that other than following command.

```
$PIN_HOME/pin -t somepintool.so -- /usr/sbin/sshd
```

So, mainly I want to know how to use pin tool to instrument a service using systemctl, however, as I do not see any way for that, I can handle this if I know how to stop the sshd service without using systemctl.

My own thought was to kill sshd process. Is it a good idea? Any other suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure I understand why killing `sshd` without using `systemctl` would help here, however, there’s nothing stopping you from telling systemd to use `pin` when starting `sshd`; run

```
sudo systemctl edit ssh.service
```

or

```
sudo systemctl edit sshd.service
```

(depending on which file you have — Debian derivatives use `ssh.service`, Fedora and RHEL derivatives use `sshd.service), and enter

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/pin -t somepintool.so -- /usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
```

Then restart `sshd`...

The override will be stored in a snippet called `/etc/systemd/system/ssh(d?).service.d/override.conf`; deleting that will restore the default `sshd` definition.

Comment: Did you mean `sshd.service`? And what happens when I stop the service you think?

Comment: I am saying killing `sshd` without `systemctl` because with systemctl I cannot stop that once I start it using pin tool.

Comment: No, I mean `ssh.service`. Are you by any chance trying to do this while connected to the system using SSH?

Comment: I think we're hitting an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) -- OP is trying to accomplish something and feels that 'kill sshd without using systemctl' is the only way to do so. There's probably a better way - and your answer looks like a pretty good start to get there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two services that shouldn't run at the same time, consider [adding a `Conflicts=` entry in the `[Unit]` section](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) of your test service:

> `Conflicts=`
>
> A space-separated list of unit names. Configures negative requirement
>   dependencies. If a unit has a `Conflicts=` setting on another unit,
>   starting the former will stop the latter and vice versa. Note that
>   this setting is independent of and orthogonal to the `After=` and
>   `Before=` ordering dependencies.
>
> If a unit A that conflicts with a unit B is scheduled to be started at
>   the same time as B, the transaction will either fail (in case both are
>   required part of the transaction) or be modified to be fixed (in case
>   one or both jobs are not a required part of the transaction). In the
>   latter case, the job that is not the required will be removed, or in
>   case both are not required, the unit that conflicts will be started
>   and the unit that is conflicted is stopped.

So this may work (not tested):

**pin-sshd.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Pin debugging of sshd (copied from sshd.service)
After=syslog.target network.target auditd.service
Conflicts=sshd.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/pin -t somepintool.so -- /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This way `systemd` can do the work of making sure you don't have both services running and show do the stopping and starting correctly. Most of the services I see that use this have `Conflicts=shutdown.target`, so it appears it's usually used for making sure services finish before shutdown occurs, but there's nothing preventing you from using this for other purposes!

Comment: Both this and the override trick will accomplish what I think the OP wants; they just do it in slightly different ways. This one is probably slightly better if you want to be able to quickly switch pinning on and off; @stephen-kitt's answer is slightly better if you're working with a service that at least occasionally gets its service file altered with a software update.